# Visualization tool for Space Rendezvous and docking

Tags: docking, rendezvous, 3d-modeling

How to make the 3D visualization the space rendezvous and docking missions once I have the data log of the operation from mathematical simulation. I found some potential tools such as SPICE and Free Flyer, though I could not understand how do I view my data logs in that software.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for? 3d-animation of spacecraft docking, or a mathematical simulation?

Comment: 3D visualization. I have the mathematical simulation of the docking and inspection.

Comment: Okay, in that case I don't know of any tailor-made solutions, but you would probably be able to feed the data into a rendering/animation software like Blender. Blender supports using python to feed in animation variables, so you would be able add spacecraft models and feed in your pre-simulated data sets as animation variables.

Comment: I'm really not sure about voting to reopen this. Like, Dragongeek's comment is to use Blender. How does this become a helpful question for the answerer that could also be helpful to someone else? There's no detail about the simulation data at all.